# How to invoke a Spring Controller from Java Filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

This is my scenario: I have two applications, both use Spring MVC. I have a Filter class in one of them and a Controller class in the other one. The requirement is a little weird, when a request is made to the application that contains the filter, this filter should invoke the controller in the another application to "keep alive" the session so I need invoking from filter class a controller class and pass as parameter the JSESSIONID. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: You want a filter in one web application to call a controller in another web application?

Comment: I think you need to provide more info on what exactly you're trying to achieve, as it's likely that your approach is not the best fit. You're trying to bridge two different gaps: (1) the filters and servlets/controllers are not meant to communicate directly (2) the webapps in a web container are usually isolated (via separate class loaders), so that interaction requires a special deployment. I have a strong feeling that you don't really wanna get there...

Comment: What is the requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I achieve my goal using [AsyncRestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/AsyncRestTemplate.html), the call to the controller from filter was something like this:

```
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.add("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + sessionId);

        HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(null, httpHeaders);

        String controllerUrl = CONTROLLER_URL;
        ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<String>> responseEntityListenableFuture = restTemplate.exchange(controllerUrl, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, String.class);

        responseEntityListenableFuture.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<ResponseEntity<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ResponseEntity<String> stringResponseEntity) {
                // Nothing to do
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                // Handle your error
            }
        });
```